# INTERNAL SELF-TEST ERROR: Printing|c|3530

Tags: warning-messages, version-10

In the last two weeks, Mathematica works correctly, but **every time** I start it, the following message appears:

[image]

The link sends me to [this page](https://www.wolfram.com/support/error-report/?Version=10.0.0&SystemID=Windows-x86-64&location=Printing-c-3530).

What happens? How can I correct it?

I run version 10.0.0 on Windows 8.1, 64 bits.

Comment: This seems to be related to the default printer on your computer. Try changing the default printer from "Device and printers" in Windows and check again. A similar question seems to be here http://mathematica.stackexchange.com/questions/32232/mathematica-sporadically-crashes-on-open

Comment: @bobknight  I changed the default printer and now it works (the other is not connected to the LAN anymore).

Comment: You should really upgrade to the latest version available to you.  That's either 10.1.0 or 10.0.2.  The latter should be available to you as it's a bug fix release.  Right now you have 10.0.0.  Many bugs have been fixed since that version.

Comment: I just solved a similar issue by also changing the default printer. In my case the error was `"INTERNAL SELF-TEST ERROR: printing|cpp|3435
Information:GetDefaultPrinterDevice failed with Windows System Error 6: The handle is invalid"`. The printer driver name causing this is "WebEx Document Loader"